# Laravel 4 Beta 5 Session Extend/Replace

Tags: php, session, laravel

I have very specific needs to the session driver because I'll be implementing an API based login with pingbacks (API specification) and I need very custom behavior of the session driver. Including database/memcached interaction at the same time. The project is "don't ask don't tell" kind of a thing xD but anyhow, any help would be deeply appreciated.

I know that laravel 4 support this kind of thing. They support custom creators but there is exactly 0 documentation on how to do that. There is no longer "Session::extend" method to use in global.php :/

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can extend/replace any Laravel class by just creating your own and then replacing it in app/config/app.php.

From Dayle: "In Laravel 4, components(core classes) are loaded by using ProviderInterfaces, these are listed within the application configs. If you change a provider to your own custom provider (for an extended class) not only will your code use the new module, but the Laravel core will also make use of these changes."

http://laravel.uservoice.com/forums/175973-laravel-4/suggestions/3150953-more-simple-way-to-extends-core-class

Answer (score 1):

I wonder what kind of specific behaviour you need. But I must remind you that using a session is the same as using any other kind of shared resource, so all principles must apply, especially protection against concurrent writes.

PHP does a pretty good job in it's standards implementation with file storage, as well as with Memcache storage. Whenever it comes to user implemented session reading and saving, locking against concurrent access is usually overlooked and forgotten. On the other hand, locking the session will serialize the execution of multiple parallel requests, and this is not the best thing for Web 2.0 applications with possibly multiple concurrent Ajax requests per session id.

I'm sorry to say this, but Laravel does a pretty bad job in this regards. Even the file driver does no locking at all, even if they try when saving the data. What they fail to implement is that the lock needs to be established before they read the data. Otherwise, the same data is read twice, and changed twice differently, and written back twice - but then first change is lost.

This concurrency problem will be really hard to debug, as it will probably not occur when using a traditional web page application without any Ajax, or Ajax only being used for reading.

So I would recommend against using the current Laravel session drivers. They do a pretty bad job writing to session files (my first question is: Why do they need to re-implement writing to files in the first place - there is already working code in PHP, which probably is also faster because it is written in C, not PHP), and the same is true for everything else they write to.

**Update:**

I first looked at the wrong source code. As mentioned in the comments, Laravel 3 is completely broken in this regards, even with files, because it does not use the native PHP session storage handler, but implements its own.

Laravel 4 used this layout up and until beta 4, and was identically broken. It only happened recently that there was a major rework that uses Symfony/HTTP-Foundation instead of their own. So Laravel 4 is not responsible for any failure now, Symfony is.

Symfony does a slightly better job, because there is actually a session storage driver that uses native PHP functionality to save sessions to files. Welcome back session locking! The \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\NativeFileSessionHandler makes a call to `ini_set()` the `session.save_handler` to `files`.

Any other storage handler (with the exception of the NullSessionHandler, for obvious reasons) does implement loading and saving the data on their own without any locking.

Lets examine an example that could be easily fixed: The `MemcachedSessionHandler`. If you look at it, you see barely any code in the `open()` and `close()` methods, but this is where the locking should take place. The only active code is in `read()` and `write()` (and `destroy()`), which is directly talking to the Memcached client object. So it is save to assume that I haven't noticed the place where the locking is going on - there is none!

Memcached actually provides a native session save handler for PHP. See http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php

The easy fix would be to mostly copy the NativeFileSessionHandler and just set the `session.save_handler = memcached` and the `session.save_path` to the Memcache cluster you want to use. The save handler implements proper locking.

There is an open issue reporting exactly this: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4976 It is open for 10 months now, which tells me that most developers rather enjoy the blazingly fast session read operation with concurrent requests than implement proper locking.

So Laravel 4 did somehow the right thing to get rid of their own implementation of buggy code (I don't have the feeling they saw this bug at that time), but now inherit the bugs of the Symfony code.

**What you should do:**

Zend Server offers the Zend Session Cluster. It works in the environment I am working with. It is transparent to PHP and has locking. It writes data to harddisk and offers high availability. I would think this is a pretty decent feature set. Think about it.

Memcached's native session save handler also has locking. I believe it is somehow lacking support for high availability, and of course any data stored on a node that goes down is lost. After all, it is only a very fast cache, not a reliable storage.

For any other storage, you need to figure out how you can acquire a lock atomically. Or deal with concurrent writes.

For example, MySQL offers to lock a dataset with `SELECT * FROM sesstable WHERE id = sessID FOR UPDATE`. Redis also offers a [locking mechanism with SET](http://redis.io/commands/set).

If locking is not what you want to do, the other option would be to try to clean up if concurrent writes did occur. CouchDB allows for conflicting writes, it is up to the client application to resolve them - the database will allow access to all different versions. Also Memcached offers `Memcached::cas` (compare and swap), which will write only if the already stored value has not changed. Read back the stored value on failure, trying to merge with the current dataset, and try again.

Comment: If you're going to make comments like these please back them up with some sources. The current Laravel 4 beta (discussed by OP) provides a native session handler interface (through Symfony) as well as a number of other drivers. Moreover, rather than making a point here, perhaps consider filing [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues) so that the framework could be made more secure in the future.

Comment: The session handler is merely affected by Symfony. You actually made me aware that the issue I reported right after my answer here was in the 3.x branch. But I had a look at the 4 beta right now: It is broken in the same way as version 3 was. But at least it got rid of all that static calling stuff, so there is progress. :) I'll probably duplicate the issue.

Comment: Because, I don't know how advanced you are in PHP but if your project scales on multiple clusters and each request goes to a random server in a random cluster for processing, file-based session is a definite NO GO. This is why I need to implement my own drivir, with my own specific stuff

Comment: I use PHP in a corporate environment with a rather big SOA architecture on multiple web farm clusters. That's why I pay so much attention to proper locking, because it is very easy to get it wrong - and lost session data within an ordering process really can make the difference. I'll investigate further and update my answer.

Comment: But I don't have problem with race conditions o.O 
I needed a simple way to replace the whole session provider. This will sound harsh but session race condition is the least what i care about. But since you've mentioned it. 

If you use a file based session storage, how do you make sure that the file of the session will exist on every server? IMO file session is stupid thing in multi-server environment. Store it in DB or memcache and be done with it. 

For the race conditions we have a mutex lock btw, which works out just nicely.

Comment: So what is your point actually? :) The mutex lock will do the locking, and something will share the session data. Both must work together, and you shouldn't deadlock. In fact, use the Memcached session handler, and you needn't care about mutex yourself.

Comment: I also need to implement an autologin mechanism and as I said, quite specific one, that is why I need to extend/replace a driver, not use whatever they provide me with

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29255/discussion-between-sk1pper-and-sven)

Comment: I do not really understand why the session storage should have anything to do with any auto login.

Comment: I found one more strange thing about Laravel's session handling - it updates session data even when you are just reading and not writing! This caused race condition problems in one of our AJAX intensive apps and we had to patch Laravel's session with a quick&dirty workaround which compares current session contents strings and does not save session unless it really has any changes (metadata such as last-session-update does not count as a change). Here is my patch: https://gist.github.com/progmars/76598c982179bc335ebb

Comment: Writing back data after a PHP script ended is the default behavior. It should not matter if you are using proper locking of the data storage, but Laravel still isn't doing it in ANY of the variants: CacheBasedSessionHandler, CookieSessionHandler, DatabaseSessionHandler, FileSessionHandler. The problem is not new, it has been reported over and over again for various versions of Laravel, and the maintainers don't seem to fix it. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5416