# Are table based sessions in laravel serialized?

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

I read somewhere that table based sessions are problematic since they don't handle concurrency well, so is there a mechanism in session databases in laravel to handle this ?

> If you use file based sessions PHP will lock session file for whole script execution duration, which means all requests from the same sessions will be serialized on PHP level, which means they also will be serialized for single user on database level. If you change to store PHP sessions in MySQL instead this effect may be no more true and you may have number of requests executing for the same session at the same time

**source**: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/03/27/php-sessions-files-vs-database-based/ 

If i have misunderstood what the author of the article was saying, I would appreciate any clarification on the subject, thank you.

Comment: Please cite your source!

Comment: Head to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16290927/744588), I hope it sheds some light on protection against conccurent writes applied to session management.